# How would I add a button in my GameScene when a function is called in my Level1 Class?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have this level two button hidden in my GameScene and what I want is when the user completes the level 1 in my level1 class the level two button should show up in my GameScene. How would I get this to work like that? Here is some code I have that I tried to make work but nothing happens. If you need more info let me know!

```
// GameScene Class

func selectLevel() {
    let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(1.0)

    levelTwoButton.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.0, self.size.height / 2.2)
    levelTwoButton.zPosition = 20
    levelTwoButton.setScale(0.8)
    levelTwoButton.alpha = 0
    levelTwoButton.hidden = true
    levelTwoButton.runAction(fadeIn)
    levelTwoButton.name = "leveltwobutton"
    addChild(levelTwoButton)
}

//level1 Class

func nexLevelUnlocked() {
    runAction(playLevelCompleteSound)
    passLevelOne()

    GameScene().levelTwoButton.hidden = false
}

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == HeroCategory && sixthBody.categoryBitMask == GoldKeyCategory{
        nexLevelUnlocked()

        println("you win!!!!!")
    }
```

Comment: Whoa, what's going on here? `GameScene().levelTwoButton` 

Can you tell me how you're setting up your level 2 button?

Comment: Okay so my levelTwoButton is in the GameScene which is my main menu in the game. It is hidden and what I want is when the HeroCategory makes contact with the GoldKeyCategory in the level1 scene I want the levelTwoButton to not be hidden in the GameScene. Does that make sense?  Im kind of stumped right now on this part and I really need help. Thanks!

Comment: BTW I probably did it all wrong in the op because this is my first time trying to work with different classes and scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Some guy helped me in another thread I made and answered the question. Thanks @Dharmesh Kheni.

```
if firstBody.categoryBitMask == HeroCategory && sixthBody.categoryBitMask ==   
GoldKeyCategory{

GameScene().unlockLevelTwo()
runAction(playLevelCompleteSound)
println("you win and level two button unlocked in the main menu!!!!!")

NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "Leavel2")

 }
```

After that in your GameScene in your didMoveToView method read that every
    time when your view loads this way:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
/* Setup your scene here */
let unlockLeavel2 = NSUserDefaults().boolForKey("Leavel2")

if unlockLeavel2 {

    unlockLevelTwo()
}
}
```